# Sunburnt solr wildcard *:*

Tags: python, solr, sunburnt

I need a way of Using the solr wildcard *:* in sunburnt solr or is there another way of specifying 'all documents' from index then refining.Here is the code

```
....
si = sunburnt.SolrInterface(url=solr_url,http_connection=h)
search_terms = {SEARCH_TERMS_COMIN_FROM_A_FORM}

#!This is where I need help!
result = si.query(WILDCARD)#I need all the docs from the index

#then I can do this
if search_terms['province']:
    result = result.query(province=search_terms['province'])
if search_terms['town']:
    result = result.query(town=search_terms['town'])
.......#two other similar if statement blocks
#finally
results = result.execute()
```

Comment: a question like yours would get down votes quite quickly. Make an effort to make CLEAR what you want. Format your question properly, with breaking to paragraphs, and perhaps give an example of what you want to achieve. Otherwise, your question will stay unanswered till eternity.

Comment: thanks Oz123,I just reformatted it,hope it is better?

Comment: you just got an answer, so I guess it worked :-) I gave you an upvote. Keep asking WELL asked questions !

Comment: Oz123,thanks to you aswell,and the answer is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure: for this exact reason you can just use an empty query - this will work:

```
result = si.query()

if search_terms['province']:
    result = result.query(province=search_terms['province'])
if search_terms['town']:
    result = result.query(town=search_terms['town'])
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for.Thanks alot,can't upvote,wanted to.